# fastAPI sqlalchemy - inner JOIN on 2 tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a restapi up and running using the fastAPI framework, which is starting to work well.

Now: I already have my MySQL code on how to inner join on 2 tables, and I want to be able to do the same, just using sqlalchemy.

Firstly, here is my SQL code which works perfectly:

```
select `the_user`.`email_adress`, `the_exercise`.`exercise_name`, `run_the_workout`.`repetitions`,`run_the_workout`.`sets`,`run_the_workout`.`pause_time`,`run_the_workout`.`day_to_perform_the_task`  

from  `workout_plan_task` `run_the_workout`  
inner join `user_profiles` `the_user` on  `run_the_workout`.the_user=`the_user`.user_id
inner join `exercises` `the_exercise` on `the_exercise`.`exercise_ID` = `run_the_workout`.`the_exercise`
WHERE  `run_the_workout`.the_user=1
```

Now, here are my table models in SQL alchemy, representing the "user_profiles", "exercises" and the "workout_plan_task" table:

#models.py:

```
class UserProfiles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_profiles"

    user_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email_adress = Column(String, unique=True)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(Integer)
    height = Column(Integer)
    weight = Column(Integer)
    main_goal = Column(Integer)
    level_experience = Column(Integer)
    profile_created_at = Column(Date)




class Exercises(Base):
    __tablename__ = "exercises"

    exercise_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    exercise_name = Column(String)
    exercise_type = Column(String, nullable=True)
    muscle_groups_worked_out = Column(String)
    equipment_ID = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    
    
    

class WorkOutPlanTask(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workout_plan_task"

    task_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user_profiles.user_ID"))
    workout_plan_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("workout_plan.workout_plan_ID"))
    exercise_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("exercises.exercise_ID"))
    repetitions = Column(Integer)
    sets = Column(Integer)
    pause_time = Column(Integer)
    day_to_perform_the_task = Column(String)
```

inside my "crud.py" file, im trying to run the query using inner joins:

#crud.py

```
def get_workout_plan_for_user(db: Session, user_id:int):
    return db.query(models.WorkOutPlanTask).join(models.UserProfiles, models.UserProfiles.user_ID == models.WorkOutPlanTask.user_ID).join(models.Exercises, models.Exercises.exercise_ID == models.WorkOutPlanTask.exercise_ID).filter(models.UserProfiles.user_ID == user_id)
```

and inside my #main.py i have this:

```
@app.get("/all_workout_plan_tasks_for_user/{user_id}")
def get_workout_plan_for_user_by_userID(user_id: int, db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_workout_plan = crud.get_workout_plan_for_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    if db_workout_plan is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="sorry.. no workoutplans found ..")
    return [schemas.a_workout_plan_task.from_orm(v) for v in db.query(...)]
```

This gives me the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got 'Ellipsis'
```

Anyone here who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's a funny mistake, take a look at the return statement:

```
return [schemas.a_workout_plan_task.from_orm(v) for v in db.query(...)]
```

You're passing [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) to your `db.query`, and obviously, it's not the expected value.